# jQuery click event happening on parent DIV when using stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//Add Header Listeners
//Signup Listener
jQuery(".top-nav-login-links .exchange-signup").click(headerObject.toggleLightBoxSignup.bind(headerObject));

//Login Listener
jQuery(".top-nav-login-links .exchange-login").click(headerObject.toggleLightBoxLogin.bind(headerObject));

//Lightbox Close Listeners
jQuery("i.close-lightbox, div.light-box-parent").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(jQuery(this).attr("data-rel") == "signUpVisible") {
        headerObject.toggleLightBoxSignup();
    } else if(jQuery(this).attr("data-rel") == "loginVisible") {
        headerObject.toggleLightBoxLogin();
    }
});
});

var headerObject = {
isLoginLightBoxVisible : false,
isSignupLightBoxVisible : false,
isCookiesBannerVisible : true,
showServicesDropdown : false,
isMobileMenuVisible : false,
layoutElement : document.querySelector('#layout'),
toggleLightBoxLogin : function() {
    jQuery("#loginVisible").toggle();
},
toggleLightBoxSignup : function() {
    jQuery("#signUpVisible").toggle();
},
toggleMobileMenu : function() {
    if (!this.isMobileMenuVisible) {
        this.layoutElement.classList.add("active");
    } else {
        this.layoutElement.classList.remove("active");
    }

    this.isMobileMenuVisible = !this.isMobileMenuVisible;
},
closeCookiesBanner : function() {
    this.isCookiesBannerVisible = false;
    //localStorage.setItem('this.isCookiesBannerVisible', 'false');
},
onMenuItemClick : function() {
    if (('ontouchstart' in window) || window["DocumentTouch"] && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
};
  </script>

<div class="top-nav-login-links">
            <ul>
                <li class="pure-hidden-phone"><a class="exchange-signup" href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="pure-hidden-phone"><a class="login exchange-login" href="#">Log in</a></li>
                <li class="pure-hidden-tablet pure-hidden-desktop" data-ng-click="viewModel.toggleLightBoxLogin()"><i class="fa fa-user login-cta login"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div id="loginVisible" class="light-box-parent login-lightbox" data-rel="loginVisible">
     <div class="light-box-options">
        <div class="light-box-container" >
            <figure class="login-figure">
                <a id="link-expert-login" href="http://experts.blurgroup.com/">
                    <img id="img-login-expert" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shared/login_expert_logo.png" alt="Expert">
                    <figcaption class="login-figcaption">Expert</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>

            <figure class="login-figure customer-login">
                <a id="link-customer-login" href="/customer/">
                    <img id="img-login-customer" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shared/login_customer_logo.png" alt="Customer">
                    <figcaption class="login-figcaption">Customer</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
         <div class="light-box-title">Login</div>
         <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="signUpVisible" class="light-box-parent expert-sign-up" data-rel="signUpVisible">
    <div class="light-box-options">
        <div class="light-box-container">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="light-box-title">New to blur Group? Join the crowd</div>
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle close-lightbox" data-rel="signUpVisible"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am currently implementing some lightboxes which open on certain anchor ticks being click. I then have the functionality whereas when the lightbox itself or an icon within it (with the class 'close' is clicked) it should close the appropriate lightbox according to the value stored in a 'data-rel' HTML5 data attribute.

The problem I am having is that the click event is propagating to any child element within the lightbox, even when I have targeted the specific elements themselves and used event.stopPropagation().

I can't figure out why this is happening. Can someone see a problem with my code?
Thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of above situation?

Comment: Does the event is bound/fired? Can't you just provide minimalistic code to replicate your issue?

Comment: Instead of using click event directly, use "jquery on" or "jquery live" based on your jquery plugin. It'll handle for you basically.

Comment: @JeevaJsb How is that different? Why OP would need to delegate event? FYI `live() is dead`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.stopImmediatePropagation()` ?

Comment: Actually I don't understand the issue from the above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) function in place of stopPropagation